# Minifying durandal mvc 4 project using weyland does not export minified main-debug.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application, durandal, bundling-and-minification

I have a durandal 2.0 MVC 4 project and would like to minify and merge all the javascript files.

Therefore I use weyland : https://github.com/BlueSpire/Weyland

I followed the instructions in the documentation and all seems to work except there is no output file generated.

Here is my weyland config:

```
exports.config = function (weyland) {
    weyland.build('main')
        .task.jshint({
            include: 'App/**/*.js'
        })
        .task.uglifyjs({
            include: ['App/**/*.js', 'Scripts/durandal/**/*.js']
        })
        .task.rjs({
            include: ['App/**/*.{js,html}', 'Scripts/durandal/**/*.js'],
            loaderPluginExtensionMaps: { 
                '.html': 'text'
            },
            rjs: {
                name: '../Scripts/library/almond-custom', 
                insertRequire: ['main'], //not needed for require
                baseUrl: 'App',
                wrap: true, //not needed for require
                paths: {
                    'text': '../Scripts/library/text',
                    'durandal': '../Scripts/durandal',
                    'plugins': '../Scripts/durandal/plugins',
                    'transitions': '../Scripts/durandal/transitions',
                    'knockout': 'empty:',
                    'jquery': 'empty:',
                    'validation': 'empty:',
                    'jquPlugins': '../Scripts/library/plugins',
                    'lib': '../Scripts/library',
                    'service': 'services',
                    'vm': 'viewmodels',
                    'view': 'views',
                    'repo': 'repositories',
                },
                inlineText: true,
                optimize: 'none',
                pragmas: {
                    build: true
                },
                stubModules: ['text'],
                keepBuildDir: true,
                out: 'main-built.js'
            }
        });
};
```

I got the following console output from Visual Studio:

```
14>  info jshint Linting 15 files.
14>  ERR! jshint Found 3 issues while linting App/main.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/repositories/userRepository.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/services/security.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/viewmodels/account/logon.js.
14>  ERR! jshint Found 1 issues while linting App/viewmodels/account/template/forg
14>  otPassword.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/viewmodels/error/404error.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/viewmodels/shared/pageBottom.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/viewmodels/shared/pageCenter.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/viewmodels/shared/pageTop.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/viewmodels/shared/sideControl.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/viewmodels/shared/table.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/viewmodels/shell.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/viewmodels/user/controls.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/viewmodels/user/index.js.
14>  info jshint Passed for App/viewmodels/user/template/userModal.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglifying 35 files.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument key [null:67,66]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/main.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument $ [null:1,88]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument data [null:37,28]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/repositories/userRepository.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument thrownError [null:40,74]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument ajaxSettings [null:40,60]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/services/security.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument event [null:52,35]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument data [null:52,29]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/viewmodels/account/logon.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/viewmodels/account/template/forgotPassword.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/viewmodels/error/404error.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/viewmodels/shared/pageBottom.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/viewmodels/shared/pageCenter.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/viewmodels/shared/pageTop.js.
14>  WARN: Side effects in initialization of unused variable filteredItems [null:4
14>  ,8]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused variable updateTable [null:8,8]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused variable itemClicked [null:52,8]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused variable itemActivate [null:62,8]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused variable toggleActive [null:64,8]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/viewmodels/shared/sideControl.js.
14>  WARN: Side effects in initialization of unused variable filteredItems [null:4
14>  ,8]
14>  WARN: Side effects in initialization of unused variable filtered [null:10,8]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused variable filterItems [null:33,8]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused variable searchMatch [null:47,8]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument settings [null:96,53]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument parent [null:96,45]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument parent [null:125,33]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument view [null:125,27]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument action [null:110,51]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument koTarget [null:110,41]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/viewmodels/shared/table.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/viewmodels/shell.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/viewmodels/user/controls.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument app [null:1,62]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument system [null:1,54]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/viewmodels/user/index.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument context [null:13,31]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified App/viewmodels/user/template/userModal.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument newActivationData [null:562,76]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument currentActivationData [null:562,53]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/activator.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument ko [null:15,170]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument schemas [null:59,52]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument err [null:61,29]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/app.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/binder.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument element [null:453,46]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/composition.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/events.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument request [null:53,57]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument textStatus [null:53,45]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument request [null:61,57]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument textStatus [null:61,45]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument request [null:75,56]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument textStatus [null:75,44]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument data [null:75,38]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/plugins/authentication.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument repository [null:76,49]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/plugins/config.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument e [null:120,43]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument e [null:139,29]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument e [null:155,28]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/plugins/contextMenu.js.
14>  WARN: Side effects in initialization of unused variable width [null:394,16]
14>  WARN: Side effects in initialization of unused variable height [null:395,16]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/plugins/dialog.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/plugins/history.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/plugins/http.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/plugins/observable.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/plugins/router.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/plugins/serializer.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument request [null:7,49]
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument textStatus [null:7,37]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/plugins/translation.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/plugins/widget.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument depArray [null:52,59]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/system.js.
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/transitions/entrance.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument err [null:150,59]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/viewEngine.js.
14>  WARN: Dropping unused function argument area [null:116,49]
14>  info uglifyjs Uglified Scripts/durandal/viewLocator.js.
14>  main
14>  repo/userRepository
14>  service/security
14>  info rjs Packaging 49 files.
14>  vm/account/logon
14>  vm/account/template/forgotPassword
14>  vm/error/404error
14>  vm/shared/pageBottom
14>  vm/shared/pageCenter
14>  vm/shared/pageTop
14>  vm/shared/sideControl
14>  vm/shared/table
14>  vm/shell
14>  vm/user/controls
14>  vm/user/index
14>  vm/user/template/userModal
14>  text!view/account/logon.html
14>  text!view/account/template/forgotPassword.html
14>  text!view/error/404error.html
14>  text!view/shared/pageBottom.html
14>  text!view/shared/pageCenter.html
14>  text!view/shared/pageTop.html
14>  text!view/shared/sideControl.html
14>  text!view/shared/table.html
14>  text!view/shell.html
14>  text!view/user/controls.html
14>  text!view/user/index.html
14>  text!view/user/template/sideBarItem.html
14>  text!view/user/template/tableItem.html
14>  text!view/user/template/userModal.html
14>  durandal/activator
14>  durandal/app
14>  durandal/binder
14>  durandal/composition
14>  durandal/events
14>  plugins/authentication
14>  plugins/config
14>  plugins/contextMenu
14>  plugins/dialog
14>  plugins/history
14>  plugins/http
14>  plugins/observable
14>  plugins/router
14>  plugins/serializer
14>  plugins/translation
14>  plugins/widget
14>  durandal/system
dransitions/entrance
durandal/viewEngine
durandal/viewLocator
========== Rebuild All: 14 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't know how to figure out what is going wrong here.

Comment: you should put this as an answer and mark it as answered.. It'll help other people who had the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to just add a refresh almond-custom.js.

I looked into the changes and apparently there was the following function missing:

```
function onResourceLoad(name, defined, deps){
        if(requirejs.onResourceLoad && name){
            requirejs.onResourceLoad({defined:defined}, {id:name}, deps);
        }
    }
```

Can't explain why the function wasn't there because it is the same version of the file as it was. (0.2.0). That's it.